# "click" event handler not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php page that prints out a div having multiple anchor tags with different IDs. Here is a sample code:

```
echo "<div id=\"pageLinks\">";
echo " <a href=\"javascript:;\" id=\"1\"><<</a> ";
echo "another link...."
echo "</div">;
```

The javascript code that should listen for the `click` event is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#pageLinks a").click(function(){
       alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

but it's apparently not working (I cannot see the "clicked" alert).
Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't think that cursing is welcome here.

Comment: Your html is broken. You should be using entities. I'm talking about the `<<` part in your links.  Also, don't put the JS protocol in your href

Comment: thanks for the edit..i was just too frustrated to give it a proper title!!

Comment: Have you tried .each() by the way?

Comment: @JohnP, what would you put in the href? #?

Comment: @Kraz Yup, you can put #. Just handle the behavior in the JS code and not in the HTML

Comment: Well, cursing may be unwelcome, but I can certainly understand your frustration. I count cursing high on my list of programming languages!

Comment: @edem why should he use .each()? there is no need for it here

Comment: @JohnP and Aakash: it's better to not use an anchor element if you don't want to link to another (part of the) page: using `#` will add an entry to the history. Just use an ordinary link and enhance its behaviour using JavaScript.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that 1 is a valid id. Look at the debug console and fix any problems there before debugging this.

Comment: @Marcel yup, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML source code is totally broken. You should use `&lt;` instead of `<` and close your last div properly.

Your javascript code btw is working, check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/raszi/H9dnE/3/

*UPDATE*

A possible better code:

PHP:

```
echo '<div id="pageLinks">';
echo '<a href="#" id="1">&lt;&lt;</a>'
echo 'another link...';
echo '</div>';
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("div#pageLinks a").click(function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    alert("Clicked!");
  });
});
```

Can be checked here: http://jsfiddle.net/raszi/p3Ug2/

Comment: did you fix your last div as well?

Comment: It should be `&lt;` and not `&gt;`.

Comment: @KARASZI i fixed everything..still won't work! thanks anyways

Comment: then, the problem is not with this part of your code. have you checked the jsfiddle links?

Comment: @KARASZI yea, one more thing, this <div> with anchor tags is delivered by AJAX..does it make any difference?

Comment: It's still better to put large chunks of HTML outside of PHP tags (so just use `?><div id="…">…</div><?php`).

Comment: @Marcel this little code here is part of a big project..there aint no way i can generate this code by html

Comment: @Aakash yes, absolutely. Probaly your javascript code runs before the AJAX part places the HTML inside your DOM. Make sure you call your binding part again after the AJAX success.

Comment: @KARASZI thank you so much sir!! the problem was that the content was being delivered by AJAX and i was firing the event way before the content actually existed!! learned a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code this way:

```
echo "<div id=\"pageLinks\">";
echo " <a id=\"1\">&lt;&lt;</a> ";
echo "another link...."
echo "</div>";
```

And then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#pageLinks a").click(function(){
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

should work. Do not put wrong HTML code in the page! And use HTML entities (`&lt;`, `&gt;`) instead of `<` and `>`

Comment: To be more precise, those are called HTML entities, not escaped symbols.

Comment: No need to be sorry ;) (I just like to use the correct terms for concepts, I've seen things like [JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) and [<p> tag](http://perfectionkills.com/tag-is-not-an-element-or-is-it/) too much) BTW, thanks for the edit of the question, I've seen *way* too many trivial edits of low-rep users last months, and they're problematic, because they block editing of the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, too! I really do not like bad questions, reading which you cannot understand the problem and, eventually, the solution ...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the html source code. Probably you can see it's messed up somehow. Maybe it helps also I you use echo with single quotest...in any case you don't have to escape the double quotes anymore and your codes gets more readable.